# Python & Tensorflow: How to multiply the dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

My goal is to train an NN, that will be able to sort images into categories (0 to 4). I have my own dataset consisting of ~20000 photos and I'm using ResNet50 as a foundation. But I need to improve its accuracy, so data augmentation seems to be the solution. I have some function that will change the image a bit, but I need to enlarge the dataset (2x, 4x or 10x...) so I'll have more data. How can I do that, without physically creating duplicates on my disk?

So, for example, if the categories are as follows:

> 0: 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ....
>
> 1: 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ....
>
> 2: 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ....
>
> 3: 0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ....
>
> ...

I need this for the NN to see:

> 0: 0.jpg, 0_copy0.jpg, 0_copy1.jpg, ....
>
> 1: 0.jpg, 0_copy0.jpg, 0_copy1.jpg, ....
>
> 2: 0.jpg, 0_copy0.jpg, 0_copy1.jpg, ....
>
> 3: 0.jpg, 0_copy0.jpg, 0_copy1.jpg, ....
>
> ...

So the augmentation process will then create enough variations.

The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')

DATASET_PATH = "MY_DATASET"
CLASS_NAMES = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]

img_height,img_width=180,180
batch_size=32

data_augmentation = tf.keras. Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomContrast(0.3),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomBrightness(0.3)
])

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  DATASET_PATH,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  DATASET_PATH,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)


batch_size = 32
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

def prepare(ds):
  # Use data augmentation only on the training set.
  ds = ds.map(lambda x, y: (data_augmentation(x, training=True), y), 
                num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

  # Use buffered prefetching on all datasets.
  return ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

train_ds = prepare(train_ds)

for idx, img in enumerate(train_ds):
  train_ds[idx] = data_augmentation


resnet_model = Sequential()

pretrained_model= tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False,
                   input_shape=(180,180,3),
                   pooling='avg',classes=len(CLASS_NAMES),
                   weights='imagenet')

for layer in pretrained_model.layers:
        layer.trainable=False

resnet_model.add(pretrained_model)
resnet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
resnet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
resnet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))


resnet_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

class_names = CLASS_NAMES

epochs=5
history = resnet_model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)

resnet_model.save("LOCAL_PATH/output.h5", save_format="h5")

fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.axis(ymin=0,ymax=1)
plt.grid()
plt.title('Model Accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'])
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.grid()
plt.title('Model Loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preprocess a tf dataset by using standard or customized functions. For instance, you could use option 2 from [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation):

```
aug_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (resize_and_rescale(x, training=True), y))
```

Have a look on how to do data augmentation for TensorFlow datasets.:

[TensorFlow Image Data Augmentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation)

Comment: I have seen this, but how much does this change the data size? I thought that this just applies the augmentation to the existing dataset, I need to expand it.

Comment: That's true. I think there isn't a dedicated feature in Tensorflow that give you the possibility to specify that you want to generate new images and increase your train set. You need to create and save these augmented images on your disk and then train the model.